# Distribute globally a metadata database keeping low latency

Tags: database, performance, search, networking, distributed

I am testing a concept of a distributed database of metadata.
The objective is to be able to do a basic search engine with decentralized storage.
It is only a concept, so it would be good to do so with a small amount of data (~1TB) and each peer should not have more than 5Gb.

How is it possible to search for indexes this fashion and in a fraction of second?

I know it is possible(look at [YaCy](http://www.yacy.de/en/)), i just don't know what are the possible ways to do so.

Comment: If the source for YaCy is available, I'd grab that and see what they're doing! Google has also published some details of how their engine works; read those too. I don't think this is an easy problem.

Comment: @simonatrcl I would, if i knew java... i will try do find its implementation, but i don't know how easy is to contact its developers. I think that google is not relevant here, it is centralized.